Orbits of the action of the Chevalley group of type B_n in characteristic 2
I would like to learn more about the orbits of the action of the Chevalley group of type $B_n$, with $n$ even, on its representation of highest weight $\omega_n$, which is isomorphic to the Clifford algebra, over an algebraically closed field of characteristic 2. Can someone give me some references which can help me to find the orbits.

Since there are different numbering and notational conventions, it's probably best to say.  Is $\omega_n$ the fundamental coweight corresponding to the short simple root?

I use the Bourbaki notation. At the end of chapters 6, 7 there are plates in which described all the classic type Lie groups. For B_n the fundamental weight $\omega_n=(\alpha_1+2\alpha_2+...+n\alpha_n)$
and it is indicated that the representation with highest weight $\omega_n$ is miniscule and of dimension $2^n$. It is also known that this representation is isomorphic to Clifford algebra.
